# Javascript string encoding Windows-1250 to UTF8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've an angularjs app that receive data from an external webservice.

I think I'm receiving UTF-8 string but encoded in ANSI.

For example I get

```
KLMÄšLENÃ
```

When I want to display

```
KLMĚLENÍ
```

I've tried to use decodeURIComponent to convert it but that doesn't work.

```
var myString = "KLMÄšLENÃ"    
console.log(decodeURIComponent(myString))
```

I'm probably missing something but I can't find what.

Thanks and regards,
Eric

Comment: `Äš` can't be UTF-8 as `š` is `0x0161`. In fact, `Ě` and `Í` encoded in UTF8 would be hexadecimal sequences `0xC4 0x9A` and `0xC3 0x8D` respectively. Here both `0x9A` _Single Character Introducer_ and `0x8D` _Reverse Line Feed_ are unprintable characters so `KLMĚLENÍ` mojibaked to UTF-8 would look like `KLMÄ�LENÃ�` in console with `�` _Replacement Character_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder). (Be beware! some browser does not support it.)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var dataView = new DataView(this.response);
    var decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
    var decodedString = decoder.decode(dataView);
    console.log(decodedString);
  } else {
    console.error('Error while requesting', url, this);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Java servlet code for simulating server side output:

```
resp.setContentType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
os.write("KLMĚLENÍ".getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();
```

Comment: Thx, That doesn't solve my issue as I have to make it work on IE, but I've requested a change on the webservice that will solve it for me. However your solution seems good in the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Just modernized version of the original answer:

```js
await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buff => new TextDecoder('windows-1250').decode(buff));
```