# Convert Windows-1252 to UTF-8 with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, character-encoding

I have strings with some dutch characters in a csv file which I should read in PHP and JS.

For PHP I am using the `iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $str );` approach to convert `Windows-1252` to `UTF-8` format. It works fine when I use `fgetcsv` and `iconv`.

**[DEMO IN PHP](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test2.php)**

**CODE IN PHP**

```
<?php

function convert( $str ) {
    return iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $str );
}

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<strong>Before Conversion:</strong><br>';
        echo '<pre>' . var_dump($data) . '</pre>';
        $data = array_map( "convert", $data );
        echo '<strong>After Conversion:</strong><br>';
        echo '<pre>' . var_dump($data) . '</pre>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Now since there is no equivalent for `iconv` in JS, I have tried to run a PHP script with AJAX and get the result.

**[DEMO in JS(AJAX)](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test3.php)**

**Code: JS:**

```
<script>
    jQuery.get('test.csv', function(data) {
        var storeData = data;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "stores-encode.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {data: storeData},
            success: function(result){
                document.write(result);
            },error: function(){
                document.write('error');
            }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**PHP (stores-encode.php):**

```
<?php

$str = $_POST['data'];

$str = iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $str );

echo $str;

?>
```

If you check the [demo](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test3.php) you can see the strings before and after conversion. I am unable to do the conversion. Can anyone help how can I convert the character sets to include those letters.

You can have a look at the csv file [here](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test.csv).

Comment: Downloaded test.csv - it's still Windows 1252

Comment: Yes exactly. But when I read the values from the csv file. The character sets are not visible on browser

http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test3.php

Comment: Why don't you proxy the csv file through php, that would convert the encoding? - I mean probably not the nicest solution, that you would be looking for, but it would work.

Comment: try checking this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39411706/7581087 (limited support though)

Comment: Trying to use fgetcsv now to get data from csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the charset value in test3.php from UTF-8 to Windows-1252 since the charset of the data is Windows-1252.

So you need to replace:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">` with `<meta charset="Windows-1252">`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I changed it to Windows-1252 but still didn't work. http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test3.php

Comment: Well your code shows you are trying to convert from windows-1252 to utf8, but your question says you are trying to convert from utf8 to windows-1252. Please correct your question. Your charset tag should be UTF-8 and not windows-1252

Comment: thanks for correcting me. Modified my question and also changed the charset back to UTF-8

Comment: Try to replace iconv( "Windows-1252", "UTF-8", $str ); with utf8_encode($str) in store-encode.php.

Comment: Still does not work. I don't think the problem should be with the iconv function because as you can see in my question, it works fine with PHP when I get the data using getcsv function. The problem is when I get the data with jQuery .get method it does not work

Comment: Can you add the line alert(data) under var storeData = data; in test3.php

Comment: added to console . Please check

Comment: Well can you get the contents of csv file directly using Php ?. For example you can use: $str = file_get_contents("http://thejobupdates.com/pt/csvtest/test.csv"); and then convert the data using php

Comment: Yes I have done that already. I just wanted to know why it is not working with jQuery.get.

Comment: Well the charset of the data is windows-1252, but the jquery.ajax assumes default charset of utf-8. you can add content_type parameters to jquery.ajax. For example: contentType: 'charset=windows-1252'. See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136594/discussion-between-nadir-latif-and-kiran-dash).