# Reading text file with special characters using d3.request

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

I have a `file.txt` that I need to get to my script and parse via d3.request.

The content of file is encoded with windows-1250 encoding and has extra lines to be deleted, so that only lines starting with 'Date' and '2017' should pass.

So far I have been using cli solution to grep text file (removing extra lines) and use d3 dsv2json to get clean json which can be loaded.

```
$ grep -E '^(Date|2017)' file.txt > file.csv

$ dsv2json -r ';' --input-encoding windows-1250 --output-encoding utf-8 < file.csv > file.json
```

However now i need to do these operations programmatically once txt file is loaded in the script via d3.request.

```
d3.request('file.txt')
  .mimeType('text/csv')
  .response(function(response) {
    // response.responseText
})
```

The`responseText` gives me raw data with wrong encoding and extra lines. How to fix it so it will produce clean json at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I have found solution.

To decode file I used solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951794/javascript-string-encoding-windows-1250-to-utf8/39411706#39411706) with TextDecoder. In order to do this d3.request.response should be set to `arraybuffer`.

```
function decode(response) {
  const dataView = new DataView(response);
  const decoder = new TextDecoder("windows-1250");
  const decodedString = decoder.decode(dataView);
  return decodedString
}
```

To filter out extra lines I used following step:

```
function filterData(rawData) {
  return rawData
    .split(/\n/)
    .filter(row => (row.startsWith('Data') || row.startsWith('2017')))
    .join('\n')
}
```

So finally, in context of d3.request:

```
d3.request('file.txt')
 .header('Content-Type', 'text/csv;charset=windows-1250')
 .mimeType('text/csv')
 .responseType('arraybuffer')
 .response(function(xhr) {
   const decoded = decode(xhr.response)
   const filtered = filterData(decoded)
   const json = d3.dsvFormat(';').parse(filtered)
   return json
  })
 .get()
```